# will a lab feel deterred from hiring me if my undergrad thesis is in a different subfield?

Tags: job-search, undergraduate, research-undergraduate, research-assistantship

i've interned at the same lab for two summers, and they highly encouraged me to apply for a research assistant position in the spring. however, i am concerned that they will not hire me based on my undergrad thesis topic.

the lab focuses on developmental neuroscience. i conducted research in the neuroanatomical etiology of autism spectrum disorder in children during the school year. but, my senior neuroscience honors thesis is on neuropolitics, technology, and radicalization. i love developmental neuro, but i'm fascinated by neuropolitics as well, and i was wondering if these dual interests are a deterrent at this point in my career.

any feedback is welcome and of help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have some history there, it seems very unlikely that such a thing would be a detriment. In fact, it might be viewed as positive that you aren't "too narrow" in your education and outlook.

But, it is up to them and you only learn by applying.

And picking a topic for such a narrow reason as obtaining a short term internship would be, I think, a mistake.